# Extract first four characters after a special character ("|") in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below contents in a cell

0001 abc|0002 eXtreme Scale|0003 Infrastructure dept. no.|0004 Integration Components

I would like to extract only the numbers (0001,0002 etc.). Can anybody please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will write all numbers to cells in column A starting from `A1` to the bottom:

```
Sub NextTest()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tmpArr As Variant
    Dim strTxt As String
        strTxt = "0001 abc|0002 eXtreme Scale|0003 Infrastructure dept. no.|0004 Integration Components"
        tmpArr = Split(strTxt, "|")

    For i = 1 To UBound(tmpArr)
        Cells(i, "A") = "'" & Left(tmpArr(i - 1), 4)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either loop over your string

```
Dim strNumbers = left(cellcontent, 4)
Dim nPipeLoc = InStr(5, cellcontent, "|", Text)
While ( nPipeLoc > 0)
    strNumbers = strNumbers & "," & Mid(cellcontent, nPipeLoc, 4)
    nPipeLoc = InStr(nPipeLoc + 1, cellcontent, "|", Text)
End While
```

Or you can use a RegEx

```
Dim strSearchRegex = "(?:^|\|)(\d{4})"
```

Or the solution of @KazimierzJawor, which is much simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that you could use in multiple ways.

Insert a module and type (copy/paste) this in:

```
Public Function PipeNumberExtractor(CellValue As String) As String
    Dim PipeSplit() As String
    PipeSplit = Split(CellValue, "|")

    Dim PipeSplitItem As Variant
    Dim SpaceSplit() As String

    For Each PipeSplitItem In PipeSplit
        SpaceSplit = Split(PipeSplitItem, " ")
        If UBound(SpaceSplit) >= 0 Then
            PipeNumberExtractor = PipeNumberExtractor & "," & SpaceSplit(0)
        End If
    Next PipeSplitItem

    If Len(PipeNumberExtractor) > 0 Then
        PipeNumberExtractor = Mid(PipeNumberExtractor, 2)
    End If

End Function

' To test the function, let's do this    
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print PipeNumberExtractor("0001 abc|0002 eXtreme Scale|0003 Infrastructure dept. no.|0004 Integration Components")
End Sub
```

In Excel, if A1 contains `0001 abc|0002 eXtreme Scale|0003 Infrastructure dept. no.|0004 Integration Components`, in A2 you can type

```
=PipeNumberExtractor(A1)
```

And you will get

```
0001,0002,0003,0004
```

Comment: The intent of this function was to create a comma separated list of numbers from the string. To get each number in a separate row, see a couple of other answers in this thread.

Comment: I have multiple lines in a single row:

0033 kundeportal
0640 Portalrammeverk
1289 eXtreme Scale
0679 Autentisering / Tilgangskontroll
0823 DnB NOR API, Webservice
0947 Integration Components
4577 Felix Kunde
4612 Sentral Infrastruktur Felix
0032 DnB Integrasjon
0022 NETS
0311 SETA
How to split each of these lines into multiple rows?

Comment: Is this entire string `0033 kundeportal 0640 Portalrammeverk ... 0311 SETA` in a single cell like `A1`? If yes, do you want the output to be like this: `0033 kundeportal` goes in `B1`, `0640 Portalrammeverk` goes in `B2` etc?

Comment: ..Yes ..you are right..I need the output 0033 kundeportal in B1 , 0640 Portalrammeverk  in B2 and so on...